# How to add dummy rows in MakeTable Query - Access 2000?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this picture:
[image: add dummy rows in MakeTable Query]

As you can see the field "promet" can go from 1 to 9. However for tipprod = "02" promet has values of 1, 2, 3, 5 and 7.

I want to add dummy rows for missing values of promet, 4, 6, 8 and 9, and I want to do it for other values of tipprod, like "03" for example or "04" etc...

Here is an example of my query with some columns removed:

[image: add dummy rows make table query 2]

How can i do that?

Comment: Just for information's sake, what values do you want for the other columns of these new missing records?  I think you would almost certainly need some dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Others can be zeroes :"0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going for a pure SQL answer:

First, create a query that returns the dummy variables:

```
SELECT A.tipprod, B.promet
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT tipprod FROM T11_nezbirni) AS A, (SELECT DISTINCT promet FROM T11_nezbirni) AS B
```

And then just left join the rest of your query to that on tipprod and promet

Comment: Actually, he might just want to insert the result of your query into a new table, then drop the old one.  And also one assumption here is that all possible values appear at least once somewhere in the current table +1.

Comment: Yup. If that assumption is invalid, you can just write out all the possible values you want in a different table, and use that instead of the `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I wrote an article about this. It is still on-line:

[Find and Generate Missing Values in an Access Table](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

It lists the numbers missing, but you should be able to modify the code to also append these to the table.